# ASP Ajax Calendar Extender and displaying time

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendarextender

I am using the Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar Extender control. In some fields though I want to display the time along with the date. I have tried just setting the Format to "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" but the time section gets wiped off. If the user wants to change the time section they can do it manually, the calendar drop down is only used for changing the date part.

Are there any workarounds or alternatives to get this working?

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar issue and I'm planning to use a Date field and an associated time dropdown (in 1/2 hour increments).  User sets the date in the date field, optionally using the calendar control, and pulls down to a valid time.  I plan to have one selection in the time drop down be a "don't care" in case it an "all day" event.

[EDIT] I found this jquery [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DateTimepicker) that I may end up using.   I also found a link to [Gaia DateTimePicker](http://samples.gaiaware.net/Extensions/DateTimePicker/Overview/) in the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279766/datetimepicker-control) (which now looks to be deleted, probably because the OP was asking for WPF controls, not web controls).

Comment: I may end up going similar route with two controls if all else fails.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the jquery plugin.  I was having the same problems with the ASP.NET AJAX DateTime calendar control, and looking for alternatives.

Comment: The update linked is http://samples.gaiaware.net/Extensions/DateTimePicker/Overview/

Answer (score 2):

The [Ra-Ajax Calendar](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Ajax-Calendar.aspx) is coming out with TIME support this upcoming Friday (28th of Nov. 2008) and it's LGPL licensed...

Comment: Do you know where to find a sample with TIME support?

Comment: I don't know we have an example if it, but you could use the Ra DateTimePicket which exists in the same projects as the Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Based on CalendarExtender, you can set the format as "MM/dd/yyyy". After the user select the date in calendar, it will return 04/28/2009 for example. In the date selected event, you can append the current time after the date returned.

OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateselect"

```
    function dateselect(ev)
    {
        var calendarBehavior1 = $find("Calendar1");
        var d = calendarBehavior1._selectedDate;
        var now = new Date();
        calendarBehavior1.get_element().value = d.format("MM/dd/yyyy") + " "+now.format("HH:mm:ss")
    }
```

Comment: This is the only way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add  time component to the AjaxControlToolKit CalendarExtender, is to append it using OnClientDateSelectionChanged and JavaScript.

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ce1" runat="server" PopupButtonID="calImg" Enabled="true" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtLeft" PopupPosition="TopRight" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="AppendTime"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

and

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //this script will get the date selected from the given calendarextender (ie: "sender") and append the
    //current time to it.
    function AppendTime(sender, args) {
        var selectedDate = new Date();
        selectedDate = sender.get_selectedDate();
        var now = new Date();
        sender.get_element().value = selectedDate.format("dd/MM/yyyy") + " " + now.format("hh:mm tt");
    }
    </script>
```